# Error in login form when try to log in

Tags: php

I am having a login problem with my form. Please can anyone help me to find what is the error.

When I'm trying to log, it always show login failed. My data base table name is *sign_up* and fields are *id*,*Name*,*Gender*,*Email_id*,*Username*,*Password*

Code for my login form ( *loginform.php* ) :

```
<?php session_start();?>
<html>
    <?php
        include('connection.php');
        $obj = new connection;
        $obj->connect();
    ?>
    <body>
        <?php session_destroy();
            session_unset();
        ?>
        <h3 align="center"> LOGIN </h3>
        <table align="center">
            <form action="login.php" name="frm" method="post">
                <tr><td>Username</td><td><input type="text" name="txt1" value=""/></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Password</td><td><input type="password" name="txt2" value=""/></td></tr>
                <tr><td><input type="submit" value="Login"/></td>
                <?php $query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM sign_up");
                    $row = mysql_fetch_array($query);
                    if($row[0] == 0){
                        echo '<td><a href="registerform.php">New User?</a></td>';
                    }
                ?>
                </tr>
            </form>
        </table>
        </center>
    </body>
</html>
```

and my login function (*login.php*)

```
<?php
    include('connection.php');
    session_start();
    $obj = new connection;
    $obj->connect();
    $username=$_POST['txt1'];
    $password=md5($_POST['txt2']);
    $query=mysql_query("SELECT Username,Password FROM sign_up WHERE Username='$username' and Password='$password'");
    $row=mysql_fetch_array($query);
    $user=$row['Username'];
    $pass=$row['Password'];
    if(($username==$user) && ($password==$pass))
    { 
        header("Location:welcome.php");
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Login Failed!!!";
    }
?>
```

Comment: is the password in the table saved using MD5..

Answer (score 0):

The single quote in the query is missing for `$username`. Change your query to:

```
$query=mysql_query("SELECT Username,Password FROM sign_up WHERE Username='$username' 
and Password='$password'");
```

Comment: Check whether you are getting values for $username,$password,$user and $pass in login.php page.

Answer (score 0):

try to add quote with `$username` and what is `$_REQUEST['name']`
may be you want to set username in session use `$user`

```
    $username=trim($_POST['txt1']);
     $password=trim($_POST['txt2']);
     $password=md5($password);

    $query=mysql_query("SELECT Username,Password FROM sign_up WHERE Username='$username' 
        and Password='$password'");
     $rows = mysql_num_rows($query);
     if($rows > 0) {
        $row=mysql_fetch_array($query);
        $user=$row['Username'];
        $pass=$row['Password'];
        if(($username==$user) && ($password==$pass))
        { 
        $_SESSION['name'] = $user;
        }
     }
else {
    echo 'No rows found';
}
```

Comment: check my updated answer check if your query is returning row or not with giving username and password

Comment: yes @Rakesh Sharma now its returning "No rows Found"

Comment: then you need to check is your db uaername and pass equal to input user,pass and waht's diff

Comment: you need to do upvote or accepting for any answer if you found helpful

Answer (score 0):

Please Have a look on below link

http://riturajkumar12.blogspot.in/2014/02/login-with-username-and-password-using.html

you will get you answer in details

Answer (score 0):

So first of all, you should really watch this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_jKylhJtPmI and then use prepared statements instead of that old fashioned syntax.

To produce even better code, you should think about using PDO instead of mysql function because it will allow you to change your database engine in one line of code.

Then, you should use the object syntax a lot more. Everything should be encapsulated in objects and you should only have one entry point which will be your application.

After all these changes, it should just work because you will not have that quote problem that Jenz was talking about.

To specifically answer your question, can you do a `print_r($row)` and give us the result ?